# Core Data, modifying NSManagedObject in background thread

Tags: multithreading, cocoa, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I wonder if it is OK to modify an `NSManagedObject` in a background thread, which was loaded in the main thread - and then save the context back in the main thread. I know I can not save the context from the background thread.

This is mostly dummy code (Swift), but it shows how I change properties of my objects in background thread and save the context back in the main thread:

```
var myObject = coreDataHelper.loadSomeObjectFromDB()
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
  doSomeHeavyLifting()
  myObject.someProperty = "foo"
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    coreDataHelper.saveManagedObjectContext()
  }
}
```

I'm asking because my application occasionally has random crashes related to core data and wonder if it might be due to my above workflow.

This is the exception:

> CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught
>   during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an
>   observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification. 
>   -[__NSCFSet addObject:]: attempt to insert nil with userInfo (null)

Only that I do not have any `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` defined myself.

So if this is the cause for the crashes, would it be as easy as moving the line `myObject.someProperty = "foo"` into the main queue, like so?:

```
var myObject = coreDataHelper.loadSomeObjectFromDB()
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
  doSomeHeavyLifting()
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    myObject.someProperty = "foo" //moved this line into main thread
    coreDataHelper.saveManagedObjectContext()
  }
}
```

Comment: Well it depends on the context, If your NSManagedContext was made on main thread then you can only perform actions on main thread.

Comment: Yes, the context is of course create on the main thread. That's where I load the object. So it is not only not OK to save the context in the background thread but as well one can not modify the objects in the background and then save the context in the main thread to get those changes to disk?

Comment: Well thats a no as well, you only manipulate coredata objects in same thread. Although in iOS8 Apple has released async fetching in Coredata.
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-core-data-and-asynchronous-fetching--cms-22241

Comment: Thanks. That's what I had feared. That would mean some bigger amount of refactoring for me. I updated the question with a an alternative approach. Would that theoretically be OK, since the object then is manipulated back in the main thread?

Comment: Yeah that should work.

Answer (score 1):

As described in comments (in one way or another), you cannot pass instances of `NSManagedObject` from one thread to another.  You can, however, pass `NSManagedObjectID` which is thread-safe.  You can then use `context.objectWithID(objectID)` to retrieve the object in a different thread.

In our experience with Core Data, using managed object contexts of type `MainQueueConcurrencyType` and `PrivateQueueConcurrencyType` with `performBlock` and `performBlockAndWait` worked better for us than using `ConfinementConcurrencyType` *(default)*.  So, the code will look something along the lines of:

```
// in main thread
var myObject = getObjectInMainThread()
let objectID = myObject.objectID
let privateContext = coreDataHelper.createPrivateContext() // creates a PrivateConcurrencyType context and returns

privateContext.performBlock {
    var object = privateContext.objectWithID(objectID)
    doSomeHeavyLiftingWithObject()
    // coreDataHelper should be listening to 
    // NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification and merge changes to main
    privateContext.save(nil) 
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        // because changes are merged by listening to context "did save"
        // notification, the update should already be reflected in the 
        // previously retrieved object
        myObject.someProperty = "foo" // moved this line into main thread
        coreDataHelper.saveManagedObjectContext()
    }
}
```